# TypeError: can't pickle file objects webpy and subprocess

Tags: python, session, pickle, web.py

I am trying to make this following code possible. But I keep getting "TypeError: can't pickle file objects" error. I am both new to python and webpy. Can anyone tell how can I achieve this code.

```
import web 
import subprocess

web.config.debug = False
urls = ( 
   "/start", "start",
   "/end", "end"
)
app = web.application(urls, locals())
s = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={"p": None})

class start:
    def GET(self):
        s.p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        return ""

class end:
    def GET(self):
        out, err = s.p.communicate();
        return out 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

the error I keep seeing is 
python27/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.**name**
TypeError: can't pickle file objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am, myself, a webpy newbie. Nevertheless, after doing some "research", it seems that `webpy` cannot `pickle` the `subprocess.Popen` object[1].
So, lets try the following approach -- that is, creating it in the `end` response and printing its output.

In other words:

```
import web 
import subprocess

web.config.debug = False
urls = ( 
   "/start", "start",
   "/end", "end"
)
app = web.application(urls, locals())
s = web.session.Session(
        app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={"p": None})

class start:
    def GET(self):
        s.p = ['ls', '-a']
        return ""

class end:
    def GET(self):
        out, err = subprocess.Popen(
                       s.p , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
        s.kill() # kill the session.
        return out 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[1] As you can see:

```
import pickle
import subprocess

with open('bla', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(subprocess.Popen(['ls'],
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE), f)
```

The `subprocess.Popen` returns a file descriptor and from the traceback I infer that `pickle` cannot serialize file descriptors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle file objects
```

In addition to that, the [`Pickle` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) mentions that it supports **only** booleans, integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers, strings, bytes objects, byte arrays, and None. Thus, it seems like hopeless.

## EDIT

If you insist on creating the process' file-descriptor, when receiving a `start` request from the client, You can use a dictionary to map session to a file-descriptor.

It should be like this:

```
s = web.session.Session(
        app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={"p": None})
session_map = {}

class start:
    def GET(self):
        session_map[s] = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'],
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        return ""

class end:
    def GET(self):
        out, err = session_process[s].communicate()
        session_process.pop(s, None)
        s.kill
        return out
```

Comment: actually I want to start a process in start as a part of a session. And either stop it or read out the output in end inside that session. Do you have any alternatively by which I can achieve this ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Does it satisfy your requirements now?

Comment: it was my pleasure ;)